# Create Excel reports by programming from templates

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using "Apache POI" to generate Excel report. I've a well designed Excel template. I want to create a report by filling the data into predefined locations of the template. That is to say, I do not want to care about the formats of the report. Is that possible? Could you give me some instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my answer. I can use the "Cell Naming" utility in Microsoft Excel and then use the following code to locate the cell and do something.

```
    CellReference[] crefs = this.getCellsByName(wb, cName);

    // Locate the cell position
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(crefs[0].getSheetName());
    Row row = sheet.getRow(crefs[0].getRow());
    Cell cell = row.getCell(crefs[0].getCol());

    // Write in data
    cell.setCellValue(cellRegion.getContent());
```

"cName" is the cell's name predefined in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: What is _this.getCellsByName_ ?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at jXLS, I think that's what you are looking for.

It takes a Excel as template and you can write a Java app to fill the data:

http://jxls.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can load you template file like any other XLS. And then make the changes you want to the specific cells and write it out into another file.

Some sample code:

Load file

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream ("D:\\book_original.xls");
            POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem (inputStream);

            HSSFWorkbook      workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fileSystem);
```

do stuff

```
HSSFSheet         sheet1    = workBook.getSheetAt (0);
            Iterator<Row> rows     = sheet1.rowIterator ();

while (rows.hasNext ())
{
Row row = rows.next ();

// do stuff
if (row.getCell(0).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
    System.out.println ("Row No.: " + row.getRowNum ()+ " " + row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("100"); 

}
```

Write the output to a file

```
 FileOutputStream fileOut1 = new FileOutputStream("D:\\book_modified.xls");
            workBook.write(fileOut1);
            fileOut1.close();
```

Comment: Hi~My data isn't placed in fixed cells. They may be move to another rows or cells. I just to want to make a mark in the Excel template and insert data into that location. Is that possible?

Comment: @Sefler: It should be possible based on how you will recognize the target row and column (i.e. cell) in the template?
If you know the number, you can do sheet1.getRow(rownum) and row1.getCell(cellnum). What is your intended means of identiyfing the target based on say cell type or cell style?

Answer (score 0):

You may also take a look at [Xylophone](https://github.com/CourseOrchestra/xylophone). This  is Java library built on top of Apache POI. It uses spreadsheet templates in XLS(X) format and consumes data in XML format.